# Populate switch case data using json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to add switch cases using json. How can I populate the data?

This is the expected output:

```
$(".custom-menu li").click(function(){
     switch($(this).attr("data-action")) {
     // A case for each action.
         case "Science": $('.abc:eq(0)').trigger('click',['Zoology']); break;
         case "Science": $('.abc:eq(1)').trigger('click',['Botany']); break;
         case "Maths": $('.abc:eq(2)').trigger('click',['Geometry']); break;
     }
});
```

This is the structure:

```
$(".custom-menu li").click(function(){
     switch($(this).attr("data-action")) {
       //looking to populate data here
     }
});
```

jQ

```
var val;
$.ajax({url: 'subjects.json'}).done(function(d) {
    val = d;
    $.each(val, function(i, su) {
      $('case "'+su[0]+'": $('.content:eq(0)').trigger('click',['+su[1]+']); break;')
      .appendTo('data-action'); //How to refer $(this).attr("data-action")
    });
});
```

json:

```
[ [ "Science", "Zoology"],
[ "Science", "Botany"],
[ "Maths", "Geometry"] ]
```

Comment: What do you want to do in `$(".custom-menu li").click....` with action and subject and also what does `$('.abc')` click handler do

Comment: @Satpal thanks I want to trigger the `$('.abc')` click via the `$(".custom-menu li")` click. Also to trigger the click I'm passing json value to the `$('.abc')`  click.

Comment: @amdixon thanks. Doesn't make too much sense to me. You mean to pass each case to the switch statement via json? As `case "Science": $('.abc:eq(0)').trigger('click',['Zoology']); break;

Comment: have a function that looks at that json input and generates as output the switch statement ( as a string ). this string can then be `eval`d in $(".custom-menu li").click

Comment: Could you please show us your HTML code?

Comment: Are there concrete and compelling reasons for the constraints you've placed? Generating a switch statement from JSON is likely possible, but certainly not idiomatic and possibly dangerous. If you describe what you're trying to achieve in a broader way, you may get better help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you want to use a switch case.
can use a for loop and an if

```
var jsonString = '[ [ "Science", "Zoology"],[ "Science", "Botany"],[ "Maths", "Geometry"] ]';
var keyValuePairs = JSON.parse(jsonString)
for(var i = 0, l = keyValuePairs.length; i < l; i++)
{
    if($(this).attr("data-action") == keyValuePairs[i][0])
        $('.abc:eq(' + i + ')').trigger('click',[keyValuePairs[i][1]);
}
```

> **Note:**
>   keep in mind the `this` will not evaluate unless it is within the function you specified above

**EDIT:**
switch case version using eval. keep in mind using eval is frowned upon

```
var codeToEval = "";
var codeHead = '$(".custom-menu li").click(function(){\
     switch($(this).attr("data-action")) {\
     // A case for each action.'
var part1 = 'case "', part2 = '": $(".abc:eq("';
var part3 =  '").trigger("click",["', part4 = '"]); break;';
var codeFoot = '});'
codeToEval = codeHead;
for(var i = 0, l = keyValuePairs.length; i < l; i++)
{
    codeToEval += part1 + keyValuePairs[i][0] + part2 + i +
            part3 + keyValuePairs[i][1] + part4;
}
codeToEval += codeFoot;
eval(codeToEval);
```

That would run the code in the global scope
but build a string in the format the code you were describing

Comment: thanks. What does this mean `if($(this).attr("data-action") == keyValuePairs[i][0])` ?

Comment: @Becky The json you specified is an array that contains arrays. so in the first loop "i" will be 0 so the first array in the larger array ie.["Science", "Zoology"].   The 2nd "[0]" will be the first value in the smaller array in the first case would be "Science"

Comment: thanks. Since my json is saved externally can I do this as `$.each(val, function(i, su) {  $('.abc:eq(' + su[0] + ')').trigger('click',[' + su[0]] + ');   });` ? But how do I connect it with `$(".custom-menu li").click(function(){` ?

Comment: Sorry can't give you that you answer right now(i'll need to think more on it), but I haven't heard of a scenario where you can create a you can input dynamic code within a scope. so you'd need to create that entire function dynamically with eval or something similar to be run in the global scope. It won't have access to those variables within your `switch case` at the time of the `switch case` execution

Comment: @Becky. you typed "`$.each(val, function(i, su) { $('.abc:eq(' + su[0] + ')').trigger('click',[' + su[0]] + '); });`" ______ did you mean `$.each(val, function(i, su) { $('.abc:eq(' + su[0] + ')').trigger('click',[su[1]]); });` that looks more like what your expected output looks like above.

Answer (score 0):

First off, the switch will not work as you have demonstrated so I used both array elements to create that.

NOW: This is super ugly and not my recommendation but to do this you need to append script to the DOM after creating it.

First I work through the JSON to create the "menu" and the script (since I did not have your HTML for the menu/list).

Here is a fiddle to show it working: [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/4bkxqvo9/2/)

Code:

```
// create json object
var myjson = [
    ["Science", "Zoology"],
    ["Science", "Botany"],
    ["Maths", "Geometry"]
];
var myscriptStart = '$(".custom-menu li").on("click",function(){switch($(this).data("action")+$(this).data("subject")) {';
var myscriptEnd = '}});';
var myscriptMiddle = '';
// create the menu and list of click targets
$(myjson).each(function (index) {
    var key = this[0];
    var val = this[1];
    $('#menu').append('<li data-action="' + key + '"+ data-subject="' + val + '" data-target=".abc:eq(' + index + ')" >' + key + '</li>');
    $('#mytargets').append('<div class="abc">' + key + val + '</div>');
    myscriptMiddle += 'case "' + key + val + '": $(".abc:eq(' + index + ')").trigger("hack",["' + val + '"]); break;';
}).promise().done(function () {
    var myfullscript = myscriptStart + myscriptMiddle + myscriptEnd;
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.text = myfullscript; // use this for inline script
   document.body.appendChild(script);
});;
// menu click handler
$(".custom-menu li").on('rack', function () {
    var action = $(this).data("action");
    var actionTarget = $(this).data("target");
    var actionSubject = $(this).data("subject");
    $(actionTarget).trigger('click', actionSubject);
});

$('.abc').on('hack', function (e, a) {
    alert(a);//what you passed in the hack event creation
    $('#result').text($(this).text() + this.classList + $(this).index('.abc'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

THIS is the proper method to handle these type things: fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/4bkxqvo9/

```
// create json object
var myjson = [
    ["Science", "Zoology"],
    ["Science", "Botany"],
    ["Maths", "Geometry"]
];
// create the menu and list of click targets
$(myjson).each(function (index) {
    var key = this[0];
    var val = this[1];
    $('#menu').append('<li data-action="' + key + '"+ data-subject="' + val + '" data-target=".abc:eq(' + index + ')" >' + key + '</li>');
    $('#mytargets').append('<div class="abc">' + key + val + '</div>');
});
// menu click handler
$(".custom-menu li").on('click', function () {
    var action = $(this).data("action");
    var actionTarget = $(this).data("target");
    var actionSubject = $(this).data("subject");
    $(actionTarget).trigger('click', actionSubject);
});
$('.abc').on('click', function () {
    $('#result').text($(this).text() + this.classList + $(this).index('.abc'));
});
```